# Why does my script not return a record from mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a login portal with mySQL and PHP

I have this file (dbc.php):

```
<?php

class db_connect {
protected $DB_SERVER = "localhost";
protected $DB_USERNAME = "root";
protected $DB_PASSWORD = "";
protected $DB_DATABASE = "mydb";

public function connect() {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->DB_SERVER, $this->DB_USERNAME, $this->DB_PASSWORD, $this->DB_DATABASE);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_errno());
    }
    return $conn;
}
}
?>
```

Then my actual PHP script (login.php) takes a POST from the login page:

```
<?php

//include database connection
include("dbc.php");
session_start();

//put post values into variables
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//create db connector object
$db = new db_connect();
$conn = $db->connect();

//select correct db
mysqli_select_db($conn,”mydb”);

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);

$query = "SELECT password FROM mydb.users WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
header('Location: sorry.html');
}


$pwhash = $result;

if (password_verify($password, $pwhash)) {
header('Location: welcome.php');
} else {
header('Location: sorry.html');
}
?>
```

This never returns a value which is odd.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to fetch data from result set then compare with `password_verify`

Comment: Have you tried using `print_r($result);` to see what data (if) `$result` holds?

Comment: If I echo out $result instead of re-directing using header, it shows that $result is empty.

Comment: Echo out ? Do you mean print_r()?

Comment: They're using `password_verify()` @Saty

Answer (score 0):

`$result` holds a MySQLi response resource, not a string or array.

You need to change this line:

```
$pwhash = $result;
```

To this:

```
$pwhash = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['password'];
```